# Relation between Ad and ad

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, adjoint-operators

Let $h(t)$ be a smooth curve in a matrix Lie group *G*, with $h(0)=e$. Let $v \in T_e G$. Then it holds that

$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\left(Ad_{h(t)}(v)\right)\right|_{t=0} = ad_{\left.\frac{d}{dt} h(t) \right|_{t=0}}(v).$$

... I have been trying to figure out if this holds in a general Lie group. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#Proof).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to use that formula for this proof? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it holds in general.

**Hint:** $\operatorname{ad}=\operatorname{Ad}'(0)$ + chain rule.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont’t Think i understand the hint (or I don’t know how to use it). For fixed $v$ in the Lie algebra, $Ad_{g(\cdot)}(v) : I \mapsto \mathbb{g}$ is the composition of $g: I \mapsto G$ and $Ad_{(\cdot )}(v) : G\mapsto \mathbb{g}$. And the only chain rule I can think of is $\frac{d}{dt}|_{0} Ad_{g(t)}(v) = T_e Ad_{\dot}(v) /circ T_0 g(\dot) (\frac{d}{dt}|_0)$ ... But I don’t see if this leads me to the wanted expression.

Comment: Ok, I get I now, thanks. I don't get the $ad=Ad′(0)$-hint though... I guess you just meant the usual definition of $ad_v u$ in terms of the $t$-derivative of $Ad_{exp(tv)}u$ at 0.

Comment: For me, $\operatorname{Ad}$ is the adjoint representation of a Lie group $G$ in its Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. So, $\operatorname{Ad}$ is a Lie group homomorphism from $G$ into $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak g)$. And $\operatorname{Ad}'(e)$ (that's what I meant, not $\operatorname{Ad}(0)$; sorry about that) is the adjoint map from $\mathfrak g$ on $\operatorname{End}(\mathfrak g)$ (that is, $\operatorname{ad}(X)(Y)=[X,Y]$).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#Proof) I am meant to illustrate... I am a physicist, so I'd "translate" your and the WP language to something 9 out of 10 physicists use in the trenches every week...

$$
h(t)= e^{t(X+ t Y+ O(t^2))}, \qquad h(0)=\mathbb {I}, \qquad h'(0)=X\\
\operatorname{ Ad}_{h(t)} (v) = h(t)~ v ~h^{-1} (t),  
$$
so that, per WP 's basic Lemma, 
$$
\operatorname{Ad}_{h(t)} (v) = e^{\operatorname{ad}_{t(X+ t Y+ O(t^2))}  } (v) = v + t ~ \operatorname{ad}_X (v) + O(t^2)~.
$$
hence 
$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\left(\operatorname{Ad}_{h(t)}(v)\right)\right|_{t=0} = \operatorname{ad}_{\left.  h'(t) \right|_{t=0}}(v),$$
where $\operatorname{ad}_X (v)= [X,v]$, linear in *X*, as used above.

I know you'd like this further translated in respectable mathematese, but the connection to the WP proofs and the Rossman text where they came from might be evident.

Comment: As I understand this, you assume that the Lie group is a matrix group? My original question was to show the identity for more general Lie groups.

Comment: Yes. I assume that. I have 0 practical experience with Lie groups that are not matrix or at least linear operator groups. I simply outlined the generic framework for orientation purposes, a trail map, assuming you might be able to fuss the fine print to your satisfaction on the basis of the WP article and references therein.